# center subview using autolayout and visual format

Tags: objective-c, macos, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I am working on an application and in the UI I have two subviews inside superview. To organize them graphically I am using autolayout and visual format. 
My question is, how could I center the two superviews horizontally?
So far I have:

```
 parent addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subview1]|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                      metrics:metrics
                        views:views];

      parent addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subview2]|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                      metrics:metrics
                        views:views];

      parent addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview1][subview2]|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                      metrics:metrics
                        views:views];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: subviews are not centered.

Comment: Do you know how to center just 1 view? If so, you can place the two subviews in a container view and just center the container view.